# Serial port emulator or simulator

Tags: serial-port, emulation

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS on a PC with **no** serial ports. I have a Qt application that needs to connect to a serial device.  I have written a simulator for this device as well.

I need a way of emulating or simulating a serial port for these two applications to communicate - they are both running on the same PC, for now.

On Windows, I used VSPE to simulate the serial port, and that works fine.

I have searched for something similar on Linux. I found:

- Socat - I have no idea how to set it up for my scenario
- Komport - does not seem to be what I need
- MaxiCom - cannot get it compiled and installed

Is there a way to set up Socat for me to use, or another application to achieve the same result?  It need not be free.

Answer (score 1):

I never heard of the programs your talking about.
At least i found tty0tty that worked great for me,
but i didn't have to link two programs, just wanted
to simulate a nullmodem cable between to serial ports.

https://github.com/freemed/tty0tty