# Virtual serial port software

Tags: networking, serial-port, virtual-console

Is there any software for Ubuntu 14.04 which allows one to open virtual serial ports?

I mean a virtual serial terminal... I need to open a serial port like ttyS0 without actually connecting any hardware. So two exe files written in C for example communicating with each other and sending ascii characters through serial read and write.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serial port emulator or simulator](http://askubuntu.com/questions/448945/serial-port-emulator-or-simulator)